# How to create an Audio Conditional GAN Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to create a GAN that outputs Audio of the digits 0-9. My data is WAV files of people saying the digits 0-9 that I've converted to Numpy arrays. I can reload these arrays and play them with librosa and I can hear the digit clearly. I've created the model and it runs without error. I'm using a similar model that I've used for an MNIST conditional GAN, and I thought all I would need to change is the shape of the model inputs.

During the training loop I save copies of both the real audio sample and the generated fake sample. If I play back the real sample I can hear it, the fake sample it sounds like white noise.

I'm trying to determine if the model just isn't learning, or if I'm ruining the sample at some point during generation.

I have 2700 samples, of size (256,64). Below is the model and some of the other functions:

```
X_train = torch.tensor(X_train)
y_train = torch.tensor(y_train)
print("X_train Shape:", X_train.shape)
print("y_train Shape:", y_train.shape)
dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X_train, y_train)

X_train Shape: torch.Size([2700, 1, 256, 64])
y_train Shape: torch.Size([2700])

loader = DataLoader(
    dataset,
    batch_size=30,
    shuffle=False,
)
```

```
class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels, features_d, num_classes, x1_size, x2_size):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        self.x1_size = x1_size
        self.x2_size= x2_size
        self.disc = nn.Sequential(
            # input: N x channels x 64 x 64
            nn.Conv2d(channels+1, features_d, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1), #in_channels = channels+1
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
            # _block(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding)
            self._block(features_d, features_d * 2, 4, 2, 1),
            self._block(features_d * 2, features_d * 4, 4, 2, 1),
            self._block(features_d * 4, features_d * 8, 4, 2, 1),
            # After all _block output is 4x4 (Conv2d below makes into 1x1)
            nn.Conv2d(features_d * 8, 1, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=0),
        )
        self.embed = nn.Embedding(num_classes, x1_size*x2_size) # Adds an additional channel

    def _block(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding):
        return nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding, bias=False,
            ),
            nn.InstanceNorm2d(out_channels, affine=True),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        )

    def forward(self, x, labels):
        embedding = self.embed(labels).view(labels.shape[0], 1, self.x1_size, self.x2_size) # for sound, size will need to be 2 variables
        x = torch.cat([x, embedding], dim=1) # Num_samples x c x size(h) x size(w)
        return self.disc(x)
```

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels_noise, channels_img, features_g, num_classes, x1_size, x2_size, embed_size):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.x1_size = x1_size
        self.x1_size = x1_size
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            # Input: N x channels_noise x 1 x 1
            self._block(channels_noise+embed_size, features_g * 16, (16,4), 1, 0),  # img: 4x1
            self._block(features_g * 16, features_g * 8, 4, 2, 1),  # img: 16x4
            self._block(features_g * 8, features_g * 4, 4, 2, 1),  # img: 32x8
            self._block(features_g * 4, features_g * 2, 4, 2, 1),  # img: 64x16
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(
                features_g * 2, channels_img, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1
                
            ),
             #Output: N x channels_img x 64 x 64
            nn.Tanh(),
        )
        self.embed = nn.Embedding(num_classes, embed_size)
    def _block(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding):
        return nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(
                in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding, bias=False,
            ),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )

    def forward(self, x, labels):
        # latent vector z = num_samples x noise_dim x 1 x 1
        embedding = self.embed(labels).unsqueeze(2).unsqueeze(3)
        x = torch.cat([x, embedding], dim=1) 
        return self.net(x).to(device)
```

```
def gradient_penalty(critic, labels, real, fake, device="cpu"):
    BATCH_SIZE, C, H, W = real.shape
    alpha = torch.rand((BATCH_SIZE, 1, 1, 1)).repeat(1, C, H, W).to(device)
    interpolated_images = real * alpha + fake * (1 - alpha)

    # Calculate critic scores
    mixed_scores = critic(interpolated_images, labels)

    # Take the gradient of the scores with respect to the images
    gradient = torch.autograd.grad(
        inputs=interpolated_images,
        outputs=mixed_scores,
        grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(mixed_scores),
        create_graph=True,
        retain_graph=True,
    )[0]
    gradient = gradient.view(gradient.shape[0], -1)
    gradient_norm = gradient.norm(2, dim=1)
    gradient_penalty = torch.mean((gradient_norm - 1) ** 2)
    return gradient_penalty


def save_checkpoint(state, filename="celeba_wgan_gp.pth.tar"):
    print("=> Saving checkpoint")
    torch.save(state, filename)


def load_checkpoint(checkpoint, gen, disc):
    print("=> Loading checkpoint")
    gen.load_state_dict(checkpoint['gen'])
    disc.load_state_dict(checkpoint['disc'])
```

```
gen.train()
critic.train()

for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
    
    for batch_idx, (real, labels) in enumerate(loader):
        #print(batch_idx)
        real = real.to(device)
        cur_batch_size = real.shape[0]
        labels = labels.to(device)
        np.save(f"/content/drive/My Drive/Pytorch_Real/Real_array_{epoch}", real.detach().cpu().numpy())
        # Train Critic: max E[critic(real)] - E[critic(fake)]
        # equivalent to minimizing the negative of that
        for _ in range(CRITIC_ITERATIONS):
            noise = torch.randn(cur_batch_size, Z_DIM, 1, 1).to(device)
            fake = gen(noise, labels).to(device)
            np.save(f"/content/drive/My Drive/Pytorch_Fake/Fake_array_{epoch}", fake.detach().cpu().numpy())
            critic_real = critic(real, labels).reshape(-1).to(device)
            critic_fake = critic(fake, labels).reshape(-1).to(device)
            gp = gradient_penalty(critic, labels, real, fake, device=device)
            loss_critic = (
                -(torch.mean(critic_real) - torch.mean(critic_fake)) + LAMBDA_GP * gp
            )
            critic.zero_grad()
            loss_critic.backward(retain_graph=True)
            opt_critic.step()

        # Train Generator: max E[critic(gen_fake)] <-> min -E[critic(gen_fake)]
        gen_fake = critic(fake, labels).reshape(-1)
        loss_gen = -torch.mean(gen_fake)
        gen.zero_grad()
        loss_gen.backward()
        opt_gen.step()

        # Print losses occasionally and print to tensorboard
        if batch_idx % 10 == 0 and batch_idx > 0:
            print(
                f"Epoch [{epoch}/{NUM_EPOCHS}] Batch {batch_idx}/{len(loader)} \
                  Loss D: {loss_critic:.4f}, loss G: {loss_gen:.4f}"
            )

            with torch.no_grad():
                fake = gen(noise, labels)
                # take out (up to) 32 examples
                img_grid_real = torchvision.utils.make_grid(real[:32], normalize=True)
                img_grid_fake = torchvision.utils.make_grid(fake[:32], normalize=True)

                writer_real.add_image("Real", img_grid_real, global_step=step)
                writer_fake.add_image("Fake", img_grid_fake, global_step=step)

            step += 1
```

Comment: Your inputs, tensors of size (1, 256, 64), seem like some sort of spectrogram rather than raw audio. Possibly Mel Spectrogram or MFCC? If so, please share the process by which the raw audio is converted to 2D spec form and how you are converting it back for listening later.

Comment: The tensors are spectrograms. I use Librosa.stft to convert from WAV into Spectrogram. Then I use librosa.istft to convert the generated tensors back to WAV. I didn't use Mel Spectrograms or MFCC because I've heard it's very difficult to convert these back into WAV audio.

Comment: I see. After you use stft, the result is the *complex* 2D tensor of stft coefficients (let's call this `S`). Since `S` is complex, you can't pass it to the model as it is; you must be passing `abs(S)`? The loss of the complex terms can cause some slight changes during reconstruction. Also, are you doing anything like normalizing the audio or spectrogram in advance? Like norming the 2D spectrogram to 0.0-1.0 range before passing to model, or doing norm scaling such that the mean is 0 and standard deviation is 1? It could be that this is causing some inconsistency.